# MS Access one subform to view many tables with similar formats

Tags: ms-access, subform

I have 30+ tables of individual vendors with similar fields (Part_Number, Description, Vendor_Code) that I want to project in a subform within a form.

Eg. if you key in a vendor code in a unbound textbox, the subform will show the particular table then you can edit and add/delete records.

I'm not sure if it's possible or not. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Images:
Example of 1 table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGodq.png

Comment: Yes it's possible with VBA code. Is it always just one table for the one vendor code? Or is it possible that one vedor code could exist in multiple tables - then what's the plan? Or are you thinking it would show all the matching records from ALL the tables at once?

Comment: Its always just one vendor code per table. Thats because I have 30+ individual vendors and their "capabilities" are listed in each individual table.
The result I am looking for is exactly above on Eg.

I tried many solutions on the web but all of them requires some relationships between the table which I don't know how to apply to mine :(

Answer (score 1):

Best solution would be to copy the data from all tables to one common table and display only part of data, related to selected vendor.

As an alternative you can create UNION query, which will merge all data from tables.

One more alternative is changing RecordSource for details subform when selected new vendor.

Only first solution will allow to do not touch application code if you vill have any changes in quantity of vendors

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Solution 1 leaves my data too messy. I already have a union query for some other form in the database, however I cannot edit the individual tables from the union query if I base a form on it.

Comment: I will try sol 3 and inform you how it turns out. Thanks for your input

Comment: Sergey is right; use one table. That can - by definition - not be more "messy" than a union query. In fact, it will be less messy - as your question demonstrates.